# iOS 7: Custom UILabel new value prints on old value

Tags: ios, uilabel

My custom `UILabel` is created every time in `[self refreshInterface]` method which is called every time in `[viewWillAppear]` method. It works fine until I navigate to other `UIViewController` and then back with new text for the `UILabel`.

New data gets printed on the previous one and it looks ugly. How to get rid of old value of my `label.text` before printing out the new.

code:

```
if(_coin.dublicates.count>0)
    {
        UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0, 13.0, 60.0, 20.0)];
        lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:8];
        lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenBg"]];
        lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" +%lu",(unsigned long)_coin.dublicates.count];
        [_toolbar addSubview:lbl];
    }
```

Comment: Don't keep adding new labels. Just add one. Keep a reference to it and if it is already there, simply update its text.

Comment: It doesn't help. Once created it stays on toolbar.

Comment: Yes, once create it stays. That's why you shouldn't keep adding more labels. Or at least remove the old label before adding a new one.

Comment: Good idea. How to remove the old label??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view controller is saving its views. When you return to your `viewController` and create a new `UILabel`, it just appears over the previous one.

**Like rmaddy said in his comment:**

Tie the `UILabel` to a property of your class (`viewcontroller`), and just reassign the text. That's definitely the simplest solution. `self.yourLabel.text = @"The text you want to assign";`

At around the 2:00 minute mark, this video explains how create an `IBoutlet` from a label in your `XIB` or `storyboard`. http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-iphone-app/getting-started-with-iphone/what-is-an-iboutlet-2

You could however, on `- (void)viewWillDisappear {}` remove that `UILabel` by getting a list of subviews and checking for `UILabel`, and then removing that.

Comment: I know how to create IBOUtlets. That's not the problem. I like the viewWillDesapear approach you mentioned.

Comment: Ok. Have implemented your viewWillDisappear method. now it works. Thanks.